# Two prefixes in database? Which one is valid?

Tags: database

I am trying to manually migrate an install and have come across this. My DB has some qfo_ prefixed rows and some wpaq_ prefixed rows. The qfo_ are all duplicates of the others (in other words, there is a qfo_commentmeta and a wpax_commentmeta, etc.).

To get the db hooked up, I have to change the options row, but which one? or both? And is having these two prefixes in one DB a problem?

Comment: Check for `$table_prefix` in your `wp-config.php` file <https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#table_prefix>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `wp_config.php` file...  look for a line that reads:

`$table_prefix  = 'qfo_';`

Or...

`$table_prefix  = 'wpax_';`

Which ever one is set in `wp_config.php` is the one that your WordPress site is using.  If the tables aren't being used then they're not really doing any harm other than taking up space, but once you're sure you've got everything you need from them then you can probably just drop them from the database.